# How is Sample Result Type different from Probability Result Type in Amazon Braket?

Tags: amazon-braket

Sample result type is changing my measurement_counts but its not happening with Probability result type. Why is this happening ? Does Sample result type changes something in the circuit itself ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To complete Christian's answer, here are few words and links about `probability` and `sample`.

`probability` returns the probabilities of measuring computational basis states. `probability` post-processes the results in your measurement_counts and adds a new element in `results.values`.

`Sample` returns the measurement counts of a specified target qubit set and observable. It is used to measure your qubit in a different basis (i.e. the one of the observable you specified). For instance, if you take the following snippet:

```
from braket.circuits import Circuit, Observable
from braket.devices import LocalSimulator
from braket.aws import AwsDevice

device = LocalSimulator()

circ = Circuit().h(0).sample(observable=Observable.X(), target=0)
result = device.run(circ, shots=10).result()
counts = result.measurement_counts
print(counts)
```

It will return `Counter({'0': 10})`. The circuit contains a single Hadamard gate that rotates the qubit such that it is now aligned along the X axis. `sample` is then used to measure the qubit in a basis that is defined by the eigenvectors of `Observable.X()` (represented by the Pauli X matrix). As the state is along one eigenstate of X, we only measure a single value '0' which corresponds to the measurement outcome of $|+\rangle$ state. Note that if you don't specify any result type, the observable Z (i.e. measuring the computational basis) is used.

You can find more information and examples at

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/braket/latest/developerguide/braket-result-types.html
- https://github.com/aws/amazon-braket-examples/blob/main/examples/getting_started/3_Deep_dive_into_the_anatomy_of_quantum_circuits/3_Deep_dive_into_the_anatomy_of_quantum_circuits.ipynb

Answer (score 3):

You are likely using the Braket SDK. Be aware that the Braket SDK has logic to calculate probabilities from actual quantum devices (hardware) if those are not returned by the device itself. Those are technically not a measurement.

You can refer to the raw results.json file from your task to see exactly what was returned by the device.

For the changes applied in the Braket SDK see this: https://github.com/aws/amazon-braket-sdk-python/blob/main/src/braket/tasks/gate_model_quantum_task_result.py